# How Can I display a form or formset based on the submissions of a Post - Django?

Tags: django, formset

Someone please tell me where I am going wrong. What I'm trying to do is have the user input the quantity of a product that they want and when submitted, if that quantity is more than 0 then display a form equal to the quantity. There are multiple products so I used an if statement to say where the post has this product name, display this form. The result I'm getting is just the forms for the last product sent over. So in a list of [ eggs, ham ], I only get a form for ham . Please help if possible, this is my code below.

View:

```
 if request.method =='POST':
    session = request.session._session_key
    formtype = request.POST.getlist('name')

    i = 0

    while i < len(formtype):
        for f in formtype:
            if f == 'eggs':
                 item = CompReg.objects.get(sessionid = session, name='eggs')
                 extra = item.quantity
                 listmemformset = modelformset_factory(ProBachata, form=ProBachataF,extra=extra)
                 formset = listmemformset()
            elif f == 'ham':
                 item = CompReg.objects.get(sessionid = session, name='ham')
                 extra = item.quantity
                 listmemformset = modelformset_factory(ProBachata, form=ProBachataF,extra=extra)
                 formset = listmemformset()
        i += 1

 else:
    extra = 0
```

Template:

```
  {{formset.as_p}}
```

Comment: Because everytime you set `formset` again, so it becomes the last one on the list. I think you must use something like "list of `formset`", then iterate it in template.

Comment: im pretty new to python, think you can elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i didn't fully understand your code (why used while, why you getting item.quantity from db, quantity musn't be in POST data?), but your code can be something like;

```
if request.method =='POST':
    session = request.session._session_key
    formtype = request.POST.getlist('name')

    formsets = []
    for f in formtype:
        if f == 'eggs':
            item = CompReg.objects.get(sessionid=session, name='eggs')
        elif f == 'ham':
            item = CompReg.objects.get(sessionid=session, name='ham')

        extra = item.quantity
        listmemformset = modelformset_factory(ProBachata, form=ProBachataF, extra=extra)
        formset = {'name': f, 'form':listmemformset()}
        formsets.append(formset)
else:
    extra = 0
```

Template:

```
{% for formset in formsets %}
name: {{formset.name}}
{{formset.form.as_p}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: alright this is very close, I took out the if statements because it wasnt working correctly. Then I left only one queryset for item,  and replaced the  name = 'eggs' with name = f. It is now printing the right number of forms, I just need it to print the right name with the form. - Its gives me only the last name in the dictionary, but the right amount of forms for all of them.